# How does travis CI know when a push event was made to a repo?

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I know travis clones a repo but how does a know when a push event has been made to a repository when there is no visible webhook placed on that repository. At least no visible webhook when you look at it from the github interface.

Comment: If you look in the settings of that repository, then 'Integrations and Services', you should see Travis under 'services'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, there is no visible webhook (under the webhook tab).

GitHub calls things like travis [Service Hooks](https://github.com/github/github-services).

They are available in the repo settings page.

[image: GitHub Integrations & Services]